# png black background with using SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

When I use `UIImageView` with `setImage:` (the image is from the remote server), the image data must be cached, so I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do it:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"icon_url"]]]
```

Then I run the simulator, the image is shown with a **black** background while the image file from remote server is a .png file with a **transparent** background.

PS When I use `UIImageView`'s `setImage:`, it works well, but the image can't be cached. How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the question, the background color or image caching ?

Comment: First of all what you want to do?

Comment: I use sdwebimae to cache the image data, the image shows with black background